# Not able to debug REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, linkedin-api

Below are the settings in the web.config file, for the service.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behaviors" name="ITDService.ITDService">
    <endpoint address="ITDService" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ITDService.IITDService" kind="webHttpEndpoint"  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"/>
</service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Service1Behaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!--<dataContractSerializer  maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>-->
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Then I am calling this service to get the linkedinconnections using HttpGetResponse(URL).

```
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

URL comes as  :

```
https://127.0.0.1/Services/ITDService.svc/LinkedInConnections/CANDIDATEID/1/Token/598e977e-2e22-4fce-83e7-e59459f3f447/TokenSecret/f859c946-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-5b6f42668cf7/Verifier/84251/false
```

I am getting 404 Not found error. And, main thing is I am not able to debug the code in this service though I have set includeExceptionDetailInFaults= "true" . How to debug it?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Please include your Interface and your Implementation of the service

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) to see what the actual request is that you're sending. You can look at the header information to find out the address.